# How to embed a comment in an entity-field query

Tags: database

In reviewing the slow query log, some of them are entity-field queries. With a normal select query, I can have something like:

```
$query = "/*" . __FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__ . "*/ SELECT...
```

and with pdo object notation, I can add

```
->comment(__FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__)
```

but how do I add a comment to an entity-field query? Apparently comment() is not a valid method.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the comment information via EntityFieldQuery::addMetaData, and then add the comment to the query in hook_entity_query_alter().